# error message in ode15s code

Tags: matlab

I wrote these simple codes in matlab in the separate files.
When I run this program, I get this message:

??? Attempt to execute SCRIPT ode15s as a function:

D:\app\ode15s.m

Error in ==> ode15s at 2

```
[T,Y] = ode15s(@difdif,[0 40],[1 0 0]);
```

what's the problem.

```
««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««

clc

[T,Y] = ode15s(@difdif,[0 40],[1 0 0]);

%plot(T,Y(:,3),'-o')

plot(T,Y(:,1),'-',T,Y(:,2),'-o',T,Y(:,3),'.')

«««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««

function dy = difdif(t,y)

dy = zeros(3,1);    % a column vector

dy(1) =-0.04*y(1)+10^4*y(2)*y(3);

dy(2) = 0.04*y(1)-10^4*y(2)*y(3)-3*10^7*y(2)^2;

dy(3) = 3*10^7*y(2)^2;

end
```

Comment: try to rename your first file to something else (don't use `ode15s.m`)

Answer (score 2):

[Why do I receive the error "Attempt to execute SCRIPT FILENAME as a function"?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18IIZ/) deals with your issue. `D:\app\ode15s.m` is possibly a self made script that comes first on the MATLAB search path. MATLAB's built in `ode15s.m` won't be called as intended. Change the order in your MATLAB search path or rename `D:\app\ode15s.m`.

Quoting the solution: `which ode15s -all` shows you all instances on your search path.

Answer (score 0):

You named your script as `ode15s`, the same name as the built-in function.  When matlab attempts to execute `ode15s(@difdif,[0 40],[1 0 0])`, it finds the script, not the built-in function.  Rename your script.